# Get count of Items by customer, along with count of records with different item types in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which holds Sales data and the columns in the table are Customer ID, Item ID, Quantity, Price, and Item Type.

For example:

```
Customer_ID|Item_ID|Quantity|Price|Item_Type

 1. 1001|001|25|33.50|A
 2. 1001|006|10|2.75|X
 3. 1001|153|32|45.10|B
 4. 1001|101|2|256.00|Y
 5. 1002|006|22|2.75|X
 6. 1002|033|10|33.50|V
 7. 1002|026|17|19.50|Z
...
```

- There can only be one item type for each item.

I need to pull up all distinct Customer ID along with a count of the number of items they have bought, a count of the number of items belonging to a certain Item Type in one field and a count of the number of items belonging to another Item Type in another field.
For example, lets say I have 4 records for customer 'John' with Customer ID 1001. I need to pull a count of all the items bought by 'John', which lets say numbers 4. Then I need to pull a count of all the items that have a certain item type. So lets say out of those 4 items, I need to pull a count of all records which have either an 'A' or a 'B' as an item type, which should pull up 2 items that have those labels. Then in another field I need to pull a count of all items that are of other Item Type apart from 'A' and 'B', which should pull up 2. If there no items for customers which have either 'A' or 'B'  then the row can be either 'Null' or a '0'.
so my output should look something like this:

```
Customer_ID|Count_of_Items|Count_of_AB_Item_Type|Count_of_Other_Item_Type
 1. 1001|4|2|2
 2. 1002|3|Null|3
 3. 1003|156|156|Null
 4. 1004|65|20|45
 5. 1005|10|8|2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this conditional aggregation using case inside the aggregate function:

```
select customer_id,
    count(*) as Count_of_Items,
    count(case when Item_Type in ('A', 'B') then 1 end) as Count_of_AB_Item_Type,
    count(case when Item_Type not in ('A', 'B') then 1 end) as Count_of_Other_Item_Type
from your_table
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gurwinder... This is exactly what I was looking for... Much appreciated...